# Add class to input on submit with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function which proofs the date format, if its invalid I want so add a class "highlight". Unfortunately i cant get it to work. I think because of the page reload. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
        function validatedate(inputText) {
            // Regular Expression
            var dateformat = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[.]\d{4}$/;
          if(inputText.value.match(dateformat)) {
            alert("date format is ok!");
          } else {
            alert("Invalid date format!");
            document.form1.text1.focus();
            document.form1.text1.setAttribute('class', 'highlight');
            return false;
          }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1">
        <input type='text' name='text1' /> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validatedate(document.form1.text1)" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add an event listener to the form, on the "submit" event and then you have to use [`.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) inside the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include `return` in the inline event handler:

```
onclick="return validatedate(document.form1.text1)"
```

```js
function validatedate(inputText) {
  // Regular Expression
  var dateformat = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[.]\d{4}$/;
  if(inputText.value.match(dateformat)) {
    alert("date format is ok!");
  } else {
    alert("Invalid date format!");
    document.form1.text1.focus();
    document.form1.text1.setAttribute('class', 'highlight');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type='text' name='text1' /> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validatedate(document.form1.text1)" />
</form>
```

You can also use [**Event.preventDefault()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

> The Event interface's `preventDefault()` method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be. The event continues to propagate as usual, unless one of its event listeners calls `stopPropagation()` or `stopImmediatePropagation()`, either of which terminates propagation at once.

```js
function validatedate(inputText) {
  // Regular Expression
  var dateformat = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[.]\d{4}$/;
  if(inputText.value.match(dateformat)) {
    alert("date format is ok!");
  } else {
    alert("Invalid date format!");
    document.form1.text1.focus();
    document.form1.text1.setAttribute('class', 'highlight');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type='text' name='text1' /> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validatedate(document.form1.text1)" />
</form>
```

But the preferred way is to avoid the inline event handler and attach the event using [**EventTarget.addEventListener()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> The EventTarget method `addEventListener()` sets up a function that will be called whenever the specified event is delivered to the target. Common targets are Element, Document, and Window, but the target may be any object that supports events (such as XMLHttpRequest).

```js
document.getElementById('btnSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(){
  validatedate(document.form1.text1);
});

function validatedate(inputText) {
  // Regular Expression
  var dateformat = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[.]\d{4}$/;
  if(inputText.value.match(dateformat)) {
    alert("date format is ok!");
  } else {
    alert("Invalid date format!");
    document.form1.text1.focus();
    document.form1.text1.setAttribute('class', 'highlight');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type='text' name='text1' /> 
  <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: While, yes, it does "fix" the requested by the O.P., it will fail if the form is submitted without touching the button (enter key, "send"/"submit"/"done" key on phones, ...).

Comment: Oh so simple, many thanks!